# Need Logic for allocating Space in listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I am on developing a numeric game using VB.Net. for that i need to generate the following pattern in a list box:

```
           0
         1 0  1
       2 1 0 1 2
     3 2 1 0 1 2 3
   ..................
10 9 ... 1 0 1...... 9 10
```

I had generated the pattern with the following code:

```
 Private Sub Generate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click
        Dim n As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim s As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To n
            s = ""
            For j As Integer = i To 1 Step -1
                s = s + CStr(j) & " "
            Next
            For j = 0 To i
                s = s + CStr(j) & " "
            Next
            ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
        Next
  End Sub
```

But it will not give the formatted output as required. following is the output of my code:

[image: output of the above code]

can anyone help me to format it properly?

Comment: Use a monospace font.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Sitting down with a piece of paper and trying to find a solution for this problem isn't very hard. You can calculate the number of spaces in advance (biggest problem: number of digits per number) or you can accumulate the strings into an array and center them afterwards (which is easier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is much better than my previous one:

```
Dim n As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(-n,n*2+1) _
    .Select(Function(x) Math.Abs(x))
Dim results = Enumerable.Range(0,n+1) _
    .Select(Function(x) String.Join(" ",numbers.Where(Function(i) i<=x).ToArray()))
Dim maxWidth = results _
    .Select(Function(x) x.length).Max + 2
For Each s As String in results.Select(Function(x,i) new string(" ",((maxWidth - x.length - i.ToString().Length) / 2)) + x)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
Next
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain not exact? If you mean that all zeros are not lined up, maybe it is because of the fonts.

Comment: Ok, I have tried that in LINQPad with Courier fonts and looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following. **It is not complete** so anyone who has a comment please do post. It is close to what you want though it gets kind of ugly when the input gets bigger.

```
Dim n As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
Dim s As String = ""
dim spaces as integer
For i As Integer = 0 To n
    s = ""
    For j As Integer = i To 1 Step -1
        s = s + CStr(j) & " "
    Next
    For j = 0 To i
        s = s + CStr(j) & " "
    Next
    spaces = (n)*2 - (s.length - 1 - (n-i))/2
    dim addedspaces = new string(" ",if(spaces<0,0,spaces))
    s = addedspaces + s
    ListBox1.Items.Add(s)
Next
```

My idea was try to figure out what the max length of the possible strings would be and then add half that length in spaces before each iteration minus half the length of the string in each iteration.

**There is a flaw in my logic** so i had to handle what would happen if `spaces` would be negative.

This line is what you may (or anybody else) try to tune:

```
spaces = (n)*2 - (s.length - 1 - (n-i))/2
```

I should also mention that i have tried this in `LINQPad` and not in an actual `listbox` so i wouldn't know the result in the listbox.

Comment: Since I don't have Visual Basic I can't test it, yet I suspect your solution only works for n<11: as soon as a number (`i`) may have more than one digit, your width calculation is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, with greater values it goes a bit off, but still has an effect. I said it has a flow. I posted it just as a kickstart.

Comment: You probably mean _flaw_ instead of _flow_ :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to store all the elements in an array, so you can check for the needed format later, for example:

```
Private Sub Generate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click
    '...

    Dim lines(n-1) As List (Of String)
    Dim numLen As Integer = 0

    ' For n...
        lines(n) = New List(Of String)()

        ' Fors
        lines(n).Add(j.ToString())
        If j.ToString().Length > numLen Then numLen = j.ToString().Length
```

Then you have all your numbers stored and the lenght of the longest one, then you have to print that on the ListBox:

```
' For n...
    Dim iSpaces As Integer = CInt(lines(lines.Length -1).Count * (numLen + 1) / 2)

    Dim sLine As String = New String(" "c, iSpaces)
    sLine &= String.Join(New String(" "c, numLen), lines(n).ToArray())

    ListBox1.Add(sLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to make this work correctly is to accumulate all strings into an array, then get the width of the last line as this will be longest, and the pad the previously created lines. *Then* you add these to your list box. In pseudo code (I don't speak Visual BASIC):

```
lines = array of n strings
for i = 0 to (n-1)
  lines[i] = createLine(i)
end

maxWidth = width(last entry of lines)

for i = 0 to (n-1)
  paddingWidth = (maxWidth - width(lines[i])) / 2
  padding = string with paddingWidth spaces
  lines[i] = padding + lines[i]
  // Or even: lines[i] = padding + lines[i]
  // That way all lines should have the same length
end
```

Also, as was pointed out in a comment, you may want to make sure to use a monospace font.